# Sending data from Express to React via Contentful API

Tags: javascript, express, reactjs, es6-promise, contentful

I've decided to try out Contentful's headless CMS, and I'm running into an issue with their API client. What I'm trying to do is marry Express with React for server-side rendering, and I'm using [this repo](https://github.com/zen-js-code/react-universal-web-apps/blob/simple+ssr+context+promises/app/infra/route-manager.js) as my starting point.

**My Express Router**

Create A Route My React Component Can Call:

```
createApiRouter(app) {
    const router = express.Router();

    this.createHeroesRoute(router);
    // this.createDetailedBillRoute(router);        
    return router;
},

createHeroesRoute(router) {
    router.get('/get-heroes', (req, res) => {
      this.getHeroes((err, data) => {
        if(!err) {
          res.json(data);                                    
        } else {
          res.status(500).send(err);
        }
      });
    });
},
```

Get The Data From Contentful:

```
getHeroes(callback) {
    contentfulClient.getEntries({content_type: 'sectionHeroes'})
      .then((entries) => {
        //serilizations is a custom data serializer to format this data, it's working fine
        return JSON.parse(serializations.serializeMainSection(entries.items[0]))
      })
      .catch((error) => error );
}
```

**My React Component**

Request the Data

```
static requestData(params, domain = '') {
    return axios.get(`${domain}/api/get-heroes`);
}
```

Set the state of the component to the data received:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.constructor.requestData().then((response) => {
      this.setState(response.data);
    }).catch((err) => {
      throw new Error(err);
    });
}
```

The point of failure is occurring in `getHeroes` method inside of express. Because Contentful's client is a promise, I'm unsure how to make `getHeroesRoute` wait on the return from `getHeroes`. How can I do this?

Comment: I've abandoned the use of Contentful's api client and instead am using `node-rest-client` and building contentful's abstractions out myself. I'd still like to know exactly why contentful's promise based responses are not working, but it is not longer a make or break issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the callback that createHeroesRoute() passes to getHeroes() when the promise resolves.  Changing getHeroes() to this should do it:

```
getHeroes(callback) {
    contentfulClient.getEntries({content_type: 'sectionHeroes'})
        .then((entries) => {
            callback(JSON.parse(serializations.serializeMainSection(entries.items[0])));
        })
       .catch((error) => error );
}
```

Assuming the JSON.parse all works.

Comment: Thanks for responding. Changing it to that now just renders an empty object... This is very strange.

Comment: Actually, changing it to that produces a syntax error, though my terminal is not telling me where the error is occuring.

Comment: You'll need to debug this step by step.  I have no idea what serializations. serializeMainSection() does, nor what entries.items[0] contains.  I'd recommend incremental logging of everything you're trying to do.  Something like this: 
    contentfulClient.getEntries({content_type: 'sectionHeroes'})
        .then((entries) => {
        callback(JSON.parse(serializations.serializeMainSection(entries.items[0])));
        })
       .catch((error) => error );

Comment: That came out pretty jumbled, apparently SO doesn't format code in comments like it does in answers.  Anyway, I'd console.log every step and see what's going on.  Do `console.log(entries);` right away to make sure your getting the data you expect, it needs to be an object with an array .items with at least one item in it.  If that looks good make sure the serializeMainSection() function returns a JSON string otherwise JSON.parse will choke.

Comment: Yeah I left some stuff out because I already did those things you're proposing. The issue is that contentful's client just isn't returning data the way the server expects. The stuff that's confusing you was stuff that I did to serialize the data in the way I thought the server wanted (and it did the trick) but contentful's client then returned an empty promise which the server tried to run with - resulting in nothing working.

Comment: So are you still getting an error?  What does it say?  Are the results of that JSON.parse() what you expect to be passing to the callback?

Comment: Yes, it comes in the shape I need it to, but the server at `res.json` is taking it in as just a Promise object rather than the data that's returned in `.then`

Comment: Aaah, your callback is looking for two things, the error and the data, so you'll need to do `callback(false, JSON.parse(....`.  Also confirm that the data is making it correctly to the callback after `if (!err) {` in your server code.

Comment: Actually what needed to be done was first parse the data so that it appears as a list instead of an object, then change the callback to only accept data (no error) because contentful returns errors in the same shape as the data. Doing so fixed everything.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem with the API, you are not waiting for the promise to resolve before sending the response. Your code should look like so:

```
getHeroes() {
  return contentfulClient.getEntries({content_type: 'sectionHeroes'})
    .then((entries) => {
      //serilizations is a custom data serializer to format this data, it's working fine
      return JSON.parse(serializations.serializeMainSection(entries.items[0]))
    })
}
```

and in your express Router :

```
createApiRouter(app) {
  const router = express.Router();

  this.createHeroesRoute(router);
  // this.createDetailedBillRoute(router);        
  return router;
},

createHeroesRoute(router) {
  router.get('/get-heroes', (req, res) => {
    this.getHeroes().then((data) => {
      res.json(data);
    }).catch((err) => {
       res.status(500).send(err);
    })
  });
}
```